# How to combine files like 'diff --unified' does it?

Tags: merge, diff

I'm looking for a solution which combines two or more input files into a single output file. The way it should work is the very same like 'diff -U 999999 file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt' does it but without the diff indicators.

Comment: Are file1.txt and file2.txt overlapping? (E.g. file1.txt contains first something uniqe, then something that is common with file2.txt, while file2.txt starts with the common part followed by something unique). The reason I ask is that if so, then I think I have a solution.

Comment: Hello hlovdal,
Yes, the two files may share common parts. Actually I want to merge two log files, where may there are parts which are overlapping and should be appear once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script I wrote to merge a bunch of log files some time ago. I started using kdiff3 manually first which worked fine for small files but became painfully and eventually unusably slow as the accumulated log grew large...

Our logs contained regular occurrences of the result of `printf("time(NULL) = %d\n", time(NULL));`, you have to adapt to find some other monotonically increasing sync mark.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

# This program takes two overlapping log files and combines
# them into one, e.g.
#
#          INPUT:                    OUTPUT:
#
#   file1        file2              combined
#    AAA                               AAA
#    AAA                               AAA
#    AAA                               AAA
#    BBB          BBB                  BBB
#    BBB          BBB                  BBB
#    BBB          BBB                  BBB
#                 CCC                  CCC
#                 CCC                  CCC
#                 CCC                  CCC
#                 CCC                  CCC
#

# This programm uses the "time(NULL) = <...time...>" lines in the
# logs to match where the logs start overlapping.

# Example line matched with this function:
# time(NULL) = 1388772638
sub get_first_time_NULL {
    my $filename = shift;
    my $ret = undef;
    open(FILE, $filename);
    while (my $line = <FILE>) {
        if ($line =~ /^time\(NULL\) = (\d+)/) {
            $ret = $1;
            last;
        }
    }
    close(FILE);
    return $ret;
}

my $F1_first_time = get_first_time_NULL($ARGV[0]);
my $F2_first_time = get_first_time_NULL($ARGV[1]);

my $oldest_file;
my $newest_file;
my $newest_file_first_time;

if ($F1_first_time <= $F2_first_time) {
    $oldest_file = $ARGV[0];
    $newest_file = $ARGV[1];
    $newest_file_first_time = $F2_first_time;
} else {
    $oldest_file = $ARGV[1];
    $newest_file = $ARGV[0];
    $newest_file_first_time = $F1_first_time;
}

# Print the "AAA" part
open(FILE, $oldest_file);
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    print $line;
    last if ($line =~ /^time\(NULL\) = $newest_file_first_time/);
}
close(FILE);

# Print the "BBB" and "CCC" parts
my $do_print = 0;
open(FILE, $newest_file);
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    print $line if $do_print;
    $do_print = 1 if ($line =~ /^time\(NULL\) = $newest_file_first_time/);
}
close(FILE);
```

The above perl script only processes two files, so I wrote the following shell script to process all the log files in one operation:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script combines several overlapping logfiles into one
# continous one. See merge_log_files.pl for more details into
# how the logs are merged, this script is only glue to process
# multiple files in one operation.

set -e

MERGE_RESULT="$1"
shift

echo "Processing $1..."
cp "$1" MeRgE.TeMp.1
shift

while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    if [ ! -s "$1" ]
    then
        echo "Skipping empty file $1..."
        shift
        continue
    fi
    echo "Processing $1..."
    perl `echo $0 | sed 's/\.sh$/.pl/'` MeRgE.TeMp.1 "$1" > MeRgE.TeMp.2 && mv MeRgE.TeMp.2 MeRgE.TeMp.1
    shift;
done

mv MeRgE.TeMp.1 $MERGE_RESULT
echo "Done"
```